# what i return in case my 2d vector size is 0

Tags: c++, vector

I have some code that outputs a 2-dimensional `vector`. I want to return a standard value if my vector size is 0 (representing that vector is empty). I searched the internet but can't find a satisfying solution.

Code :

```
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {


        vector<vector<int>> res;
        int a=nums[0],sum=0,b;
        for (int j=1;j<nums.size()-1;j++){
            b=nums[j];
            sum=a+b;
            if (search(-sum,nums,j+1)){
                vector<int> v;
                v.push_back(a);
                v.push_back(b);
                v.push_back(-sum);
                res.push_back(v);
            }
        }

        return res;
```

```
Last executed input : []
```

Error :

```
Line 923: Char 34: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type'(stdlib.h)
```

Traditionally I use return 0 in such case but now it gives error.

**Edit:**
If my code is :

```
 vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        if (nums.size()==0)
            return 0;
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        int a=nums[0],sum=0,b;
        for (int j=1;j<nums.size()-1;j++){
            b=nums[j];
            sum=a+b;
            if (search(-sum,nums,j+1)){
                vector<int> v;
                v.push_back(a);
                v.push_back(b);
                v.push_back(-sum);
                res.push_back(v);
            }
        }

        return res;
```

the **error** is :

```
solution.cpp: In member function threeSum
Line 13: Char 20: error: could not convert '0' from 'int' to 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >'
             return 0;
                    ^
```

Comment: If your return type is `vector<vector<int>>`, then the function must return an object of this type. `0` is a literal of type `int`, your function cannot return `int`, and there is no conversion constructor to be used to create a vector from `int`. There are many ways how to resolve your problem, such as returning an empty vector or wrapping a vector into `std::optional`.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Are you triyng to return vector *or* int from the same function? That's not possible.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I want to return a 2D vector

Comment: You can just remove the if (nums.size() == 0) block. If the vector nums is empty your current code will return an empty vector (res)

Comment: @RudreshDixit If you want to return a 2D vector, how could you return `0`?

Comment: @DanielLangr Actually it gives the error as I edited in the question

Comment: If you want to return a 1x1 vactor, and in it's only cell have value 0, you can `return {{0}};`, but I think it would be more meaningful to return an empty vector.

Comment: @Nico238 That's not true. If `nums` is empty, `nums.size() - 1` will cause _integer overflow_ and the loop will cause _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @DanielLangr in that case just write `vector<vector<int>> res; if(nums.size() == 0) return res; else{...}`